# Select query inside case in a postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I've been looking for a while, try a lot of codes found in SO, but none of them worked. So I'm asking a new question.

In a PostgreSQL function, I'm trying to return a SETOF bigint (bunch of ids from a table), but depending on first input (`$1`) the query would be diferent. So I have also a `SELECT CASE` in that function.

Currently, the function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_employee_ids(int, int, int, int, text, int)
RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$BODY$
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN $1 = 1 THEN
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period = $2 AND payment >= $3 AND operation = $4
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period IN $5
        WHEN $1 = 2 THEN
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period BETWEEN $1 AND $6 AND payment >= $2 AND operation = $3
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period IN $5
        WHEN $1 = 3 THEN
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period BETWEEN $1 AND $6 AND payment >= $2 AND operation != $3
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period IN $5
        WHEN $1 = 4 THEN
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period BETWEEN $1 AND $6 AND payment < $2 AND operation = $3
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period IN $5
    END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

In this case, the error is a syntax error near SELECT.
The problem seems to be that the `SELECT` is not executing. But I tried also with `RETURN QUERY`, `EXECUTE`, `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` and lot of other things from other answers here.

How can I make this work?

**Edit:**
Useful info, this is how I use the function, with these parameters: `get_employee_ids(4, 1108, 250, 97, "(1109,1110)", 0808)`

Comment: Subqueries need to be surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: Already tried, `syntax error near $5` when surronding the whole `SELECT` and `syntax error near INTERSECT` when surronding each `SELECT`.

Comment: . . Oh, that is another problem as well.  I would suggest that you just use dynamic SQL>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth argument is a text which is to be a part of a query. You cannot *build* the query this way. 
Change the parameter type to `integer[]` and use `ANY` instead of `IN`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_employee_ids(int, int, int, int, int[], int)
RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$BODY$
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN $1 = 1 THEN
            (SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period = $2 AND payment >= $3 AND operation = $4
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period = ANY ($5))
        WHEN $1 = 2 THEN
            (SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period BETWEEN $1 AND $6 AND payment >= $2 AND operation = $3
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period = ANY ($5))
        WHEN $1 = 3 THEN
            (SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period BETWEEN $1 AND $6 AND payment >= $2 AND operation != $3
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period = ANY ($5))
        WHEN $1 = 4 THEN
            (SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period BETWEEN $1 AND $6 AND payment < $2 AND operation = $3
            INTERSECT
            SELECT employee_id FROM employee WHERE period = ANY ($5))
    END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;

-- usage:
SELECT get_employee_ids(4, 1108, 250, 97, array[1109,1110], 0808);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the integer array as suggested by [@klin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33369177/131874) and this much simpler query:

```
create or replace function get_employee_ids (
    int, int, int, int, int[], int
) returns setof bigint as
$body$

select employee_id
from employee
where
    (
        ($1 in (1, 4) and payment < $2 and operation = $3)
        or
        ($1 = 2 and payment >= $2 and operation = $3)
        or
        ($1 = 3 and payment >= $2 and operation != $3)
    )
    and period = ANY ($5)
    and period between $1 and $6

$body$
language sql volatile;
```

BTW it looks like it can be `stable` in instead of `volatile`